# How to extract email id from dl tag in python using scrapy?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

```
   <dl class="personal-details">
                <!-- Personal Details:Name -->
                                        <dt>Name</dt>
                    <dd><span class="title">Associate Professor</span> <span class="fn">Wlsh</span>                     <!-- <img style="cursor: pointer; float: right;" src="/wp-content/themes_inc/images/print.gif" onclick="javascript:window.print()" alt="Print profile" title="Print profile" /> -->
                    </dd>
                                    <!-- Personal Details:Positions -->
                                    <dt>Position(s)</dt>
                    <dd><span class="role">Head of School</span><br><span class="org">Faculty of Health,<br> School - Biomedical Sciences</span></dd><dd><span class="role">IHBI Membership</span><br><span class="org">Institute of Health Biomedical Innovation (IHBI),<br> IHBI Health Projects,<br> IHBI Biomedical Sciences - IPTM</span></dd>                 
                <!-- Personal Details:Discipline -->
                                        <dt>Discipline *</dt>
                    <dd>
                    Biochemistry and Cell Biology, Microbiology                     </dd>

                <!-- Personal Details:Phone Numbers -->

                    <!-- Personal Details:Phone -->
                                                <dt class="detail-group">Phone</dt>
                        <dd class="detail-group tel">+61 7 3138 2347 </dd>

                    <!-- Personal Details:Fax -->
                                                <dt>Fax</dt>
                        <dd>+61 7 3138 1534 </dd>


                    <!-- Personal Details:Email -->

                        <dt>Email</dt>
                        <dd>
                            <!-- No spam --><a id="e" class="email" href="mailto:t.wsh@edu.au">walh@edu.au</a><!-- No spam -->
                        </dd>

                                        <dt>Location</dt>
                    <dd><a href="https://secu.au/staffdirectory/details.php?id=wsh">View location details</a> (QUT staff and student access&nbsp;only)</dd>


                <!-- Personal Details:Qualifications -->
                                        <dt class="detail-group">Qualifications</dt>
                    <dd class="detail-group">
                        <p>
                        PhD (University of Queensland), BSc(Hons) (University of Queensland)                            </p>
                    </dd>

            <!-- Start BUDDYPRESS fields -->




                            <!-- End BUDDYPRESS fields -->

            <!-- Personal Details:Keywords -->
            <!-- Displayed for steering committee - Hidden for now until determine if Meta keywords is sufficient -->
                                <dt class="detail-group">Keywords</dt>
                <dd class="detail-group">
                    <p>
                    Metabolism, Protein analysis, Proteomics                        </p>
                </dd>
    </dl>
```

from above code how to extract email id in python using scrapy? I tried this command

```
response.css('dl.personal-details dd a::attr(text)').extract()
```

but i'm getting o/p like this: `[]`. Also, using CSS i'm able to extract so many values but with Xpath i'm not able to extract even single value! why is this happening?

Comment: Have you tried using BeautifulSoup and RegEx? The combination worked for me on multiple instances.

Comment: no...i'll try..but tell me how to extract email id using CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simpleton code for filtering out the email addresses based on your requirement:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
file  = open("Path_to_file\\demo.html",'r')
soup = BeautifulSoup(file.read(),'html.parser')
addrs = soup.find_all('a')
for addr in addrs:
    if '@' in addr.get_text():
        print (addr.get_text())
```

Hope it helps..